# Setting working directory for a folder making script

Tags: python, windows, cmd, registry, contextmenu

I made a python script (UI is tkinter) which makes a folder along with its subfolders. Folder tree which needs to be made is loaded from a configuration file. It is compiled, then stored in C:\Scripts\scriptFolder along with icon and configuration file. Registry key for context menu entry is added to HKEY_..._ROOT -> Directory -> Background -> Shell. Current directory is fetched via system argument (%V in registry entry). Script is started with right-click -> `scriptName`. Script itself is working like a dream.

Here goes the problem:
My boss's request is that paths of configuration and icon files be relative in the script (and that script is compiled to .exe and stored in the aforementioned scripts folder, so we can't do that differently):

```
configFile = "res\\config.cfg"
iconFile = "res\\icon.ico"
```

If I use the `NoWorkingDirectory`, then the working folder is c:\windows\system32. Without `NoWorkingDirectory`, script opens within current folder (the one which I right-clicked in).
Is there a way to set it's working folder?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the first argument when calling the python script is the location of the script itself:
sys.argv[0] = python script location

This way I can make a path to it's location using path.split(), but it's still not a relative path...